# How to redirect a directory that not exists to another domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I want to do a 301 redirect from one site to another with this conditions:

**For example:**
I want to redirect 
http://domain1.xxx/peter and http://domain1.xxx/gabriela .. etc.. (multiple users)
to
http://domain2.xxx/mynet/peter and http://domain2.xxx/mynet/gabriela ...

The structure is:
From http://domain1.xxx/{user}
To http://domain2.xxx/mynet/{user}

There is a problem: the domain1.xxx site is empty (the peter, gabriela... subdirectories do not exist)

I have configured my .htaccess like this on the domain1.xxx .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / http://domain2.xxx/mynet/
```

If the folder exist, the redirection works, but if the directory does not exist, i get a forbidden response (for example for peter):

**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access /peter on this server.

Many thanks

Comment: Probably is better to redirect by DNS?... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(\w+)/?$ http://domain2.xxx/mynet/$1
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Hello @anubhava, sorry this is not working, i get bad response.. look  (http://responsabl.es/) and (http://responsabl.es/xxx) do not work, but  (http://responsabl.es/diarioresponsable) is redirecting to http://diarioresponsable.com/redponsable/diarioresponsable and works fine (i have created a empty diarioresponsable folder)--- :(

Comment: Probably i would need to try with PHP or with DNS Alias... What do you think @anubhava ?

Comment: `responsabl.es/diarioresponsable` works fine and correctly redirects to `diarioresponsable.com/redponsable/diarioresponsable` in my browser.

Comment: Yes but this is because i have created the diarioresponsable empty folder. If you try with another random: responsabl.es/example don´t redirect to diarioresponsable.com/redponsable/example...

Comment: Yes my .htaccess only have the line you tell me :)

`RedirectMatch 302 ^/(\w+)/?$ http://domain2.xxx/mynet/$1`

Comment: i'm going to talk with my hosting provider and i will notice here ¡thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but in the end was a problem of my hosting, bad configuration! NOw with Redirect 301 / http://domain2.xxx/mynet/ is all ok! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a apache bad configuration!

The correct way is:

`Redirect 301 / http://domain2.xxx/mynet/`

Thanks, Ciro